# How i Share Image and Text both on Skype and Facebook

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I try many of the Codes. How i share Image and text both on Facebook or Skype.

I try Below code for share image and text. Pls Help me.

`val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND) intent.type = "*/*" intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody) intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getImageUri(applicationContext, bitmap)) intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); startActivity( Intent.createChooser( intent, "Share" ) )`

Comment: set the intent type to `"image/*"`

Comment: I try this Also but not working

Comment: can you post your full code

Comment: Above Code and this code for uri
private fun getImageUri(context: Context, inImage: Bitmap): Uri {
        val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes)
        val picturePath =
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                getContentResolver(),
                inImage,
                "IMG_" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime(),
                null
            )
        return Uri.parse(picturePath)
    }

Comment: Please post your code in a normal way in a code block as it is unreadable now. Also do not post as a comment as it is yet more unreadable. Post normal please.

Answer (score 0):

so the first thing you need to fix is the intent `"/"` -> `"image/*"`, using this might issue a bug in your app because might skype or Facebook can't handle foramt types your sending, also in your ImageUri function you inserting the image into the MediaStore and that could also generate bugs like duplicate images, the function I changed it also makes sure to save the bitmap image to a temporary file in the cache directory and creates a content URI using FileProvider also add `intent.setPackage("")`:

```
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    intent.type = "image/*"
    val bitmapUri = getImageUri(context, bitmap)
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri)
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your text here")
    intent.setPackage("// For Facebook") 
    intent.setPackage("// For Skype") 
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"))
    
    private fun getImageUri(context: Context, inImage: Bitmap): Uri {
        val cachePath = File(context.cacheDir, "images")
        cachePath.mkdirs()
        val stream = FileOutputStream("$cachePath/image.png")
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
        stream.close()
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.packageName + ".fileprovider", File("$cachePath/image.png"))
    }
```

Comment: Not working Same issue. text not coming. Only Image Come

Comment: if you want to sent the text along with the image use putextra Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT with and specify the text you want to send